# systemd: how to selectively disable wpa_supplicant for a specific WLAN interface?

Tags: debian, linux-networking, systemd

On a Linux system with `systemd` and `networkd` I need to operate a WLAN access point on one WLAN interface, while operating further (hotplug) WLAN interfaces in normal station ("client") mode.

As it turns out, `wpa_supplicant.service` goes live on all my WLAN interfaces, which would be fine, if only all these WLAN interfaces would operate in station/client mode. However, while `wpa_supplicant.service` serves a WLAN interface, it's not possible (anymore?) that `hostapd.service` operates that WLAN interface in AP access point mode.

So I want to disable `wpa_supplicant.service` for a specific interface only, say `wls35u2`. My idea was to have a `wpa_supplicant@wls35u2.service` unit that I can selectively disable, but to leave `wpa_supplicant.service` enabled. However, this does not seem to work or I'm doing something wrong in the `wpa_supplicant@wls35u2.service`.

So, how can I disable the WPA supplicant service on a specific interface only without globally disabling it?

Answer (score 14):

Use the "nohook wpa_supplicant" option in /etc/dhcpcd.conf. If you don't want wpa_supplicant for wlan0 this would be:

```
interface wlan0
        nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. @Nproject found a nice solution. But you don't have to modify each of this procedures. Simply go to the end of the file Nproject mentioned (`/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant`) and modify the following if clause:

**ORIGINAL**

```
if [ "$ifwireless" = "1" ] && \
    type wpa_supplicant >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
    type wpa_cli >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        case "$reason" in
        PREINIT)        wpa_supplicant_start;;
        RECONFIGURE)    wpa_supplicant_reconfigure;;
        DEPARTED)       wpa_supplicant_stop;;
        esac
fi
```

Add `[ "$interface" != "TheInterfaceWPASupplicantShouldBeDisabledOn" ]` in this way:

**MODIFIED**

```
if [ "$ifwireless" = "1" ] && [ "$interface" != "TheInterfaceWPASupplicantShouldBeDisabledOn" ]  && \
    type wpa_supplicant >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
    type wpa_cli >/dev/null 2>&1
then
        case "$reason" in
        PREINIT)        wpa_supplicant_start;;
        RECONFIGURE)    wpa_supplicant_reconfigure;;
        DEPARTED)       wpa_supplicant_stop;;
        esac
fi
```

Additionally this will prevent the Network Manager (GUI) in your taskbar to show up this interface.

Answer (score 3):

**[EDIT: Look at @rweisse answer for a better way to do it]**

I had the exact same problem on my raspberry pi.

What i found is that both *wpa_supplicant@wlan0* and *wpa_supplicant@wlan1* (I have two wlan interfaces) and *wpa_supplicant.service* were disabled.

I managed to find (On raspbian at least, i don't know how it is on other debian releases) that **dhcpcd** is responsible for wpa_supplicant start.

Under **/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks**, there is a file named **"10-wpa-supplicant"**, in which you can find start/reconfigure/stop procedures for wpa_supplicant.

In this file i simply added condition on the **$interface** being processed. For each PROCEDURE_NAME (start/stop/reconfigure):

```
PROCEDURE_NAME( )
    if [ "$interface" != "TheInterfaceWPASupplicantShouldBeDisabledOn" ] then
        Code of the prodecure
    else
        return 0
    fi
```

After that, i restarted the dhcpcd service with

```
systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

Now the InterfaceWPASupplicantShouldBeDisabledOn is no longer a problem using hostapd.
This solution is kinda brutal, as i don't think this is supposed to be done like so, but i was not able to find any manual on how to do this another way.

Hope this helps.